# Yet another Young Double Slit Experiment

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment

If I have a laser light incident on the double slit at an angle O < 90 what kind of interference pattern will I see? Will i see the same with less intensity or different pattern?

Comment: You may want to search online for a double slit "mathlet" which allows you to interactively simulate a double slit experiment.

Answer (score 2):

The main and dominant difference of the interference pattern you get when you shine light at different angles at the slits is that the pattern is shifted. It's because the light coming at the two slits will have varying phase difference, depending on angle of incidence.

This can be easy to understand if one considers big slits with 0-sized division between them (i.e. one big slit). If you shine the light with different angles of incidence, you'll get the spot at different places. This is the place where 0th-order interference maximum will appear when you return to separated small slits.

Comment: This answer could be greatly enhanced w/ the addition of a couple equations demonstrating the positiong of the zero-order maximum, etc.